# writing the key function inside the sorted function

Tags: python

I am new to python and am trying to sort the following list of tuples:

```
>>> str
[('991', 'Shantell'), ('992', 'Cherish'), ('993', 'Linsey'), ('994', 'Hali'), ('995', 'Tarah'), ('996', 'Annemarie'), ('997', 'Asha'), ('998', 'Jada'), ('999', 'Leila'), ('1000', 'Peggy')]
```

I want to sort it based on the first value of the tuple but unfortunately the first value of each tuple is a string and not an integer. I know I can create a key function that does this :

```
def digit_key(t):
    return (int(t[0]))
```

and then call sorted like this:

```
>>> sorted(str,key=digit_key)
[('991', 'Shantell'), ('992', 'Cherish'), ('993', 'Linsey'), ('994', 'Hali'), ('995', 'Tarah'), ('996', 'Annemarie'), ('997', 'Asha'), ('998', 'Jada'), ('999', 'Leila'), ('1000', 'Peggy')]
```

Do I always have to define the key function before sorting ??
Is there a prettier way to write this code without defining two functions for it??
I tried the following and failed:

```
>>> sorted(str,key= int(str[0][0]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1112>", line 1, in <module>
    sorted(str,key= int(str[0][0]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `str[0][0]`? -- As a side note, `str` is a builtin type.  You'd probably do best to name your variable something else :)

Comment: thanks .... i will keep that in mind in future :)

Comment: What's wrong with having `digit_key` as a named function? If you want to use it in more than one place, unit-test it, ask for help debugging it, debug it yourself 6 months from now, you'll be very happy that you've defined it as a separate function. And all it costs you is one line of wasted code. Is that really not acceptable?

Comment: @abarnert : All I want to do is to convert the first element of a tuple to an integer and since int() is a BIF I was not leaning towards creating a new function just for that. But the idea of running unit test cases for complex key functions is definitely worthwhile. I never took into account that I would need to unit test my key function while posting this question .... Now that I think about it and I learnt about lamda function in python...I agree that it is not too bad to have a separate function.

Comment: @tomkaith13: The problem is that you're calling _two_ functions: `[0]` (which doesn't have a built-in equivalent, but you can get it from `operator.itemgetter`), and then `int`. So, if you want to do that without defining a new function, you need some way to compose them. Which _is_ possible… but better to just define a new function (whether by `lambda` or `def`). That's different from, e.g., Haskell, where you often don't explicitly define the functions, or C, where you rarely pass functions in the first place; it's just one of the things about "pythonic style" you have to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sorted(str,key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

The `lambda` creates a function inline which is equivalent (in this case at least) to your `digit_key`.  I'm not sure if that is "prettier", but it's less verbose and is what most people would probably use.

Comment: If the key func is non-trivial, it should be written as a named function so you can unit test it.

Comment: @gnibbler -- Of course.  `lambda` is worthless for complicated functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Lambda statements:

```
sorted(str, key= lambda a: (int(a[0])) )
```

Basically its a concise way to declare inline functions. The syntax is the `lambda` keyword followed by arguments (separated by commas), a colon, and then the statement that the function returns:

```
lambda <arg...> : <statement>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to avoid defining functions, `lambda` doesn't help; it's just a different way to define functions. You can use higher-order functions to create functions without defining them:

```
sorted(str, key=functional.compose(int, operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

(You'll need to install the [`functional`](https://github.com/abarnert/functional) module (or some other source of a `compose` function), and `import` both `functional` and `operator`.)

But I think that's kind of cheating around the definition of "define", and it's certainly not more pythonic.

Meanwhile, if you just want the prettiest, or most pythonic, or most maintainable code… maybe you've already got it.

Giving the function a name usually makes it more readable.

It also makes it much easier to debug. If `lambda foo: bar(baz(foo), qux(foo))` isn't doing the right thing, you have to try to guess what it's *supposed* to be doing before you can fix it. If the function has a name, you don't have to guess—it's supposed to be doing what the name implies.

Defining it out of line also means you can use it in multiple places, without copy-paste.

And you can unit-test it.

And it's often more efficient.

And all it costs you is one line of wasted code. Is that really not acceptable?

Obviously in simple-enough cases, `lambda` is often readable—otherwise, it wouldn't be in the language in the first place. But it's never actually necessary, and there's always a tradeoff between brevity and explicitness.